# Running script from different user

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, scripting

[image]

I want to run a script from a different user without logging into it.

I don't have permission to edit sudoers file nor do I have root access.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: Why are you using `su`? Are you using it because you have to run the command _as_ the other user, or because you don't have permission to access the file as the current user? Using `su` would effectively be the same as logging in as the other user.

Comment: You can't run a program on another user's account without logging into that account. Do you have that account's password? If so you can use `su` to run a command as that user, that's one way to log into that account just to execute one command. What's the actual problem here?

Comment: we have a script for  deployment which is triggered from jenkins and the script should run from  user1 but as per our policy we cannot ssh user1 , so we have to ssh user2 and then run the script from user1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sudo rights to run *script* as *anotheruser*, which consists in having a line in the sudoers file shaped as such:

```
saif    server = (anotheruser) /path/to/script
```

then you can run

```
sudo -u anotheruser /path/to/script
```

Otherwise, you need to know the password for the *anotheruser* account, in which case you can run

```
su -l anotheruser -c /path/to/script
```

Otherwise, there is no way to do what you want. (You explicitly stated that you do not have root access, which would allow you to run either of these commands without needing the *anotheruser* password.)

Comment: You don't need to use sudo. If you have the password to the account, you can use `su`. If you have an SSH key which is authorized in that account, you can use SSH.